# Hide a ul with jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, dom-events

JavaScript shopping cart web app.

My cart is dynamically built up on the data array you throw at it.

If the array has 5 objects you get 5 rows, if 7 then 7 rows etc.

Before building the cart the array object's -> quantity attributes are checked.

A row is only added if this attribute is above 0, naturally!

(All the above is a pretty simple explanation of how this (and probably all simple shopping carts) should work!)

---

In the quantity cell there are 2 buttons, plus and minus (obvious functionality).

They are added to the DOM at runtime as is everything.

They are bound by `addEventListener` to an update function which:

1. maintains the object array
2. redraws the cart by calls the main function the updated object array

If any of the objects quantities have reached 0 (quantity = 1 and minus button pressed <-- sorry for the over-simplification) then when the main function runs it reads the quantities and only draws rows where the object quantity >= 1.

It all works nicely - see images:

[image: inital "full" shopping basket - no zeros]

[image]

The problem is that I want to call a jQuery function to hide the corresponding row whose
quantity has become zero with a nice fade (opacity 100% to 0) or hide (height/width 100% to 0).

The logical place for this is in the update function before the main function redraws the basket!

**This the problem as far as I understand
when the value goes from 1 to 0 is not a DOM event therefore jQuery can't "see" it so doesn't fire- at least that's what I think is going on**.

Here is some code which shows cart update logic:

```
function processButtonEvent( action, buttonId ) {
//clog( 'processButtonEvent | action - ' + action + ' : but id - ' + buttonId );
var index = getRowIndex( buttonId );
var stock = getStock( index );

if ( stock > 1 && action == false ){
    stock = reduceStock( stock );
    data[index].quantity = stock;
    makeShoppingBasket(myBasket, data);
    
}else if (stock == 1 && action == false ){
    stock = removeStock( stock , index );
    data[index].quantity = stock;
    makeShoppingBasket(myBasket, data);
    
} else if ((stock >= 1 && action == true) && stock <=9 ) {
    stock = addToStock( stock );
    data[index].quantity = stock;
    makeShoppingBasket(myBasket, data);
    
} else if (stock == 10 && action == true){
    fullBasket();
}
}
```

The correct place to call the animation is within the first else-if in the `removeStock` function which looks like this:

```
function removeStock( stock, index ){
    stock = reduceStock( stock );
    // clog ('removeStock | let\'s make a nice anim!' )
    removeItemAnimation( index );
    //test();
    return stock;
}
```

this then calls `removeItemAnimation` which is in a separate file called myjquery.js
(this file does work because `showBasketHead` is called by `$document.ready` function which works!)

```
function removeItemAnimation( index ){
clog ( 'removeItemAnimation | row number : ' + (index + 1) );
var id = '#row_' + (index+1);
remRow( id );
}
function remRow( id ){
//clog('remRow : ' + id );
$( id ).hide('slow');
}
```

so finally, here's the jQuery that's not working!

```
$( id ).hide('slow');
```

Am I just not calling it right or am I right in thinking that the stock==0 is not a DOM event so cannot call jQuery?

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: maybe the element isn't passing nicely. What if you explicitly define one, does it still not work?

Comment: Too much information, but yet still not enough... can you provide complete sections of code rather than snippets? Preferably in a JSfiddle.

Comment: thanks for comments. Do you know if stock==0 can be detected by jquery? @SamCreamer -ssorry, although it said element in my code i changed it to id as that's what's being passed

Comment: And yes, you do not generally get DOM events for DOM changes. There is an old `DOMSubtreeModified` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), but not recommend for the faint of heart :)

Comment: i think if i bind a differnt event handler at runtime (with the intended jquery animation called in it) to the minus button when stock == 1 might work. Then if minus is clicked this will "trick" the DOM or create a kind of false event where the jquery gets fired!!! What do you guys think